# FileProvider - IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root share flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, share

I'm trying to share a image with plugin share flutter, but I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.../cache/share/image-777.jpg
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_path"/>
    </provider>
```

flutter:

```
    final urlImage =
          'https://images.tokopedia.net/img/cache/500-square/hDjmkQ/2021/9/13/343063bb-f7c5-468d-9602-9b06ced70bdb.jpg';

      final uri = Uri.parse(urlImage);
      final response = await http.get(uri);
      final bytes = response.bodyBytes;

      final temp = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      final path = '${temp.path}/image-777.jpg';

      File(path).writeAsBytesSync(bytes);

      await Share.shareFiles(
        [path],
        // text: wording + ' ' + url,
        // subject: 'Refer your friend',
      );
```

provider_path.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <external-path
    name="external"
    path="/" />
  <external-files-path
    name="external_files"
    path="/" />
  <cache-path
    name="cache"
    path="/" />
  <external-cache-path
    name="external_cache"
    path="/" />
  <files-path
    name="files"
    path="/" />
</paths>
```

I was searching whole day about this error and trying to understand FileProvider, but I have no idea what this error message tries to tell me, i already change '.' to '/' in provider_path.xml or '/cache/share' but still not working . If you want more info/code, write me in the comment.